# WinKey delay before menu shows

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I have a weird issue with my keyboard on Windows 10. Whenever I press the WinKey nothing happens, but when I press and hold it for about a second before releasing it, it does show the menu. This is the case for both WinKey keys on the keyboard.

Using any shortcut with the WinKey, like WinKey+E or WinKey+D just works fast as always. Using CTRL+Esc to show the menu also works immediately. It's just the loose WinKey that seems to have a second delay before working.

Anyone have any ideas what is causing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you boot into a minimal boot configuration does this behavior happen?

Comment: I did now :) The WinKey does respond immediately in minimal boot, but the start menu does not seem to work properly at all as it disappears right away. Do you have any suggestions as to how to diagnose this?

Comment: Turn off live tile, and unpin unnecessary tiles. The delay is from loading tiles mostly.

Comment: I noticed one other thing. When I create a simple Windows application that does nothing but log the keys I hit, this keyboard registers a single WinKey keypress as two events: LWin and something called BrowserFavorites. Does that mean anything to you?

Comment: @Robba - That happens in a minimal configuration?  I suspect you have an application that modifies the start menu?  Do you have any application that interacts with your browser favorites?  The reason it works if you hold the key is because something is trying to capture the key.

Comment: No it does not happen in minimal configuration, but it only happens on one of the two keyboards I have currently connected to my computer (for diagnosing this). Both keyboards are fine in minimal configuration though, but I'm not sure what happens between minimal and normal (on all 3 computers I've tried it on even)

Comment: All 3 computers are behaving identically?  You made no mention of that.

Comment: Yes, all 3 computers behave identically. I've contacted the keyboard vendor and they believe it to be a faulty keyboard, I'll just have it replaced and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall the keyboard driver from the device manager. It might be a driver issue.

Comment: Tried that, but the HID Keyboard Device will simply show up again with the same results.